# get data from promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I have some rest api, and need to get data from promise and render it.

```
const data = http.get(url) // it return the promise.

// [[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
// [[PromiseResult]]: Array(4)
```

I can console log needed data:

```
const data = http.get(url).then(res=> console.log(res.data)) // array in console
```

I read some tutorials, and allways, always it shows how to console log results, but I dont need it in concole, I need render it in component. It may be simple question, but im total new in JS.

```
const ItemsList = () => {
  const data = http.get(url) //return promise. How can I get array from thid promise result?
  return (
      <ul>
        { data.map(item => {
          return (
            <ItemPreview key={item.id} item={item} />
          );
        })}
      </ul>
  )
}

export default ItemsList
```

tried async/await. spend already 4 hours to this task, but get only errors. Just don't kwnow how to write it. can someone help, and show me how to do it. Or give me link where I can find how to render promise result in component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async`/`await` is the way to go

```
const ItemsList = async () => {
  const data = await http.get(url) 
  return (
      <ul>
        { data.map(item => {
          return (
            <ItemPreview key={item.id} item={item} />
          );
        })}
      </ul>
  )
}
```

Comment: Right! Or you can take the traditional way: function httpRequest(params, postData) { new Promise((resolve, reject) => {... resolve(body)...} } It depends what you have to do with the result. If the output of an other function is dependent on output of the current executed function then use await. but both ways are correct.